# Excel VBA copy formula until empty

Tags: excel, vba

I get my data from a system that can export to Excel, but formatting is "picture-like" and not in normal spreadsheet form (ie: names in merged cells across the top of each set of headers, time, and data; then repeat for per case) so sorting and subtotals are impossible. And, of course, it's all in text.

I unmerged all and inserted a blank column (C). Some cells in Column B have activity time (ie: "Act: 00:15") others have repeated headings.

I need to place this formula in column C "=mid(B#,7,5)" to "sort-out" the time value, but only if the word "Act:" shows up in column B. Then, I need to copy or repeat the formula down column C (which will have varying lengths per report) and subtotal each case as well as grand total.

```
Do 
    Cells.Find(What:="act:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:= False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate 

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate 
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(act,7,5)" 
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Activate 
Loop While ActiveCell = "Email me"
```

Comment: Using the word "macros" as a tag without a reference to what **kind** of macro (in this case, Excel) is pretty meaningless. Please edit to also post what you've tried so far that isn't working for you. It's typically expected that you show some effort to solve the problem yourself first before posting here; we frown on "please write my code for me" questions. :-) The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has some tips on writing questions in a way that will improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Can't you just use something like `=IF(LEFT(B#, 4) = "Act:", MID(B#, 7, 5), "")` ?

Comment: Also, no offense but you can't just open the VBA editor and throw keywords around. If you want to use a VBA macro, you need to learn how to use it properly.

Comment: Do
    Cells.Find(What:="act:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(act,7,5)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Activate
    Loop While ActiveCell = "Email me"

Comment: Alexander, I evidently just posted what I currently have saved.  I have reviewed and tried to implement several of the examples found on this forum. I tried naming the column B as "act" but learned that wasn't necessary.  I tried dim/sum but kept getting stopped due to blank cells. Ken, I know I'm green at "forums" but, "way harsh."

Comment: You need to identify which cell (e.g. B36) to plug into your `=MID...` formula. After performing the `Find` look at storing `ActiveCell.Address` into a `String` variable then plug that variable into your formula. Not sure about your terminating condition on the loop